# Escaping ONLY contents of Node in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I have a part of code mentioned like below.

```
    //Reading from a file and assign to the variable named "s"
    string s = "<item><name> Foo </name></item>";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(s);
```

But, it stops working if the contents has characters something like "<", ">"..etc.

```
string s = "<item><name> Foo > Bar </name></item>";
```

I know, I have to escape those characters before loading but, if I do like

```
 doc.LoadXml(System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(s));
```

, the tags (< , >) are also escaped and as a result, the error occurs.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is VERY hard to reason about invalid XML (it is essentially becomse instructured text). Please think what you actually want program to do in following case <item><name></item> before continuing down this route...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agree with Alexei, but another way to think of it is that you should try to stop "Foo > Bar" from ever becoming part of the XML. At the point it's added, you can simply escape it. After the XML is invalid, it becomes a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a tricky solution:

```
    string s = "<item><name> Foo > Bar </name></item>";
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"<[^>]+?>", m => HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(m.Value)).Replace("<","ojlovecd").Replace(">","cdloveoj");
    s = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s).Replace("ojlovecd", "&gt;").Replace("cdloveoj", "&lt;");
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your content will *never* contain the characters "]]>", you can use CDATA.

```
string s = "<item><name><![CDATA[ Foo > Bar ]]></name></item>";
```

Otherwise, you'll need to html encode your special characters, and decode them before you use/display them (unless it's in a browser).

```
string s = "<item><name> Foo &gt; Bar </name></item>";
```

Comment: As my comments says, those strings are read from files. They are NOT assigned in my codes. I know that contents should be encoded , but there are lots of contents in the file, and I may need lots of regex to replace all of this in my strings, I think. I don't want to those tedious regx checking.  So, my question is how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the content of string to the `InnerXml` property of node.

```
 var node = doc.CreateElement("root");
 node.InnerXml = s;
```

Take a look at - [Different ways how to escape an XML string in C#](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)

Comment: Sorry.What is the difference? It is the same apart from having extra root node. Anyway, the error will be encountered while assigning to node.Innerxml ? Will n't?

Comment: @Kai No need if you already have DocumentElement (root node).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the strings that you have generated are strings, and not valid XML. You can either get the strings generated as valid XML OR if you know that the strings are always going to be the name, then don't include the XML `<item>` and `<name>` tags in the data.

Then when you create the `XMLDocument`. do a `CreateElement` and assign your string before resaving the results.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("item");
doc.AppendChild(root);
XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("name");
name.InnerText = "the contents from your file";
root.AppendChild(name);
```